# What is the difference between \empty and \@empty?

Tags: macros, tex-core

I want to elaborate a command that would print differently simple differential `dx` and multidimensional differential `d^3x`. For this purpose I invented the command `\dif` with one optional argument. It is defined as follows:

```
\newcommand{\dif}[1][]{%
    \def\@tmp@a{#1}%
    \ifx\@tmp@a\@empty
        [b1]\mathrm{d}
    \else
        [b2]\mathrm{d}^{#1}{} \!
    \fi
}
```

Here [b1] and [b2] are added for debugging. Branch [b1] is intended for the case when the command is called without any argument, e.g. `\dif{x}`. Second branch [b2] should be taken in case where, e.g., the command `\dif[3]{x}` is used to print `d^3x`. The definition, shown above, seems to work fine. However, if `\@empty` is substituted with `\empty` first branch is always ignored.

The command `\empty` is explained in *The TeXBook*, so that initially I tried it for this code and only occasionally reverted to `\@empty` having remembered a post at this site where it was said that the  `\end` command of Plain TeX is redefined to `\@@end` in LaTeX.

> Can somebody explain what is the difference between `\empty` and
>   `\@empty` in LaTeX and, perhaps, suggest a better solution for my
>   problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `\@empty` and `\empty` macros are defined in the source file for the LaTeX format `latex.ltx` on line 122 and 441, respectively:

```
\def\@empty{}

\let\empty\@empty
```

So both are actually identical. I as well wondered about having two names for the same thing around. I guess the LaTeX developers wanted a macro which is safer for being redefined by the user or other packages.

You code actually should work with both `\@empty` and `\empty`. Put a `\show\@empty` and `\show\empty` before your `\ifx` to debug the issue. Maybe one gets redefined somewhere. In that case you could place a `\tracingall\tracingassigns=1\relax \tracingonline=0\relax` very early of your document preamble and then search for the redefinition in the log file.

Comment: I guess that `\empty` remains for historic reasons; probably at the time `lplain.tex` was written it was called `\empty` as in `plain.tex` and then `\@empty` was added for uniformity. Actually `\empty` is useful for avoiding `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` sometimes.

Comment: Guilty is `polyglossia` pkg with option `[babelshorthands]` and `\setdefaultlanguage{russian}`. It seems to redefine `\empty` since without `polyglossia` both `\empty` and `\@empty` variants take the branch [b2] wich is not what I want.

Comment: \empty to my knowledge is a plain TeX leftover.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: There is `\space` so why not have `\empty`? I mean, why having `\@empty` at all? LaTeX doesn't define a `\@space` as well.

Comment: @Martin I think the initial idea and there is a note in the LaTeX source to this effect was to remove all the plain definitions, but then LaTeX got frozen. Possibly there might have bee concerns of breaking older code.

Answer (score 11):

I get the same output either with `\@empty` or with `\empty`. I suggest you another definition:

```
\newcommand{\dif}[1][]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \else
    ^{#1}\mkern-1.5mu
  \fi}
```

This has two advantages over yours:

1. It takes care automatically of the thin space before the `d`
2. It uses a slight smaller backspace in case there's an exponent to the `d`.

Of course I'd prefer an italic `d`, but that's another story. :)

Comment: but d is _not_ a variable ...

Comment: @Herbert Should we start a religion war? :)

Comment: @Enrico: yes, please ... :-)

Comment: The ISO standard is also an upright 'd' (as of course it should be: I'm a scientist, not a pure mathematician :-)

Comment: Most importatly that this your solution works both with and without `polyglossia` package loaded. See my comment to @Martin Scharrer answer. As to italic `d`, I follow not only my taste but also this presentaion of the developer of Minion Pro Math font: http://www.typoma.com/publ/20041002-atypi.pdf.

Comment: Why `\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}` not `\mathop{d}` ?

Comment: @Igor Did you try it? With `\mathop{d}` the "d" would be lowered, not upright, *and* followed by a thin space; `\mathop{\mathrm{d}\!}` *is* equivalent, but I prefer to keep things where they belong.

Comment: @egreg I love religious wars too! Especially as God/Devil are in the details. Now why would most people treat the differential operator differently to all the others? I like your definition, I would just add an `\ensuremath' before the `\mathop`. For anyone following an obscure discussion Beccari (2007b) has some nice tips in a TUGBoat article.

Comment: @Yiannis Whether adding `\ensuremath` or not is another potential topic for a religion war. Remaining to the main topic: I know that in physics and engineering there is the need of clear standards about the symbology. This is by no means necessary in pure mathematics, where change of alphabets is done on different bases than in applied sciences. To talk mathematics: the `d` in `dx` is definitely *not* an operator, as the two letters form an inscindible unit.

Comment: @egreg You mean calling it a differential operator is a misnomer? Please note I am an Engineer so some clarity from a Mathematician is always welcome :).

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Calling it a differential operator *is* a misnomer, since in ordinary math, the "d" binds the variable of integration, that is it indicates which variable can be locally renamed ("alpha-renamed" in lambda-calculus terminology). That said, I prefer using an upright "d" because that's better from a parsing perspective.

Comment: @LoverofStructure ...the term preceded Church by 130 years or so:)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Good to know ... do you have more info on this?

Comment: The 130 is an Engineer's estimate:), based on Church developing the lambda calculus around 1930 versus  Babbage during the early 1800's forming the Analytical Society to advocate pure d-ism as opposed  to the dot-age. Probably in reality >130. From memory, but I am sure a good goog search, can throw a bit more non-Kantian enlightment.

Answer (score 3):

For the purpose of testing whether the argument of a command is empty I would recommend using the `\@ifmtarg` switch provided by the `ifmtarg` package. Thus:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifmtarg}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\dif}[1][]{%
  \@ifmtarg{#1}{[b1]\mathrm{d}}{[b2]\mathrm{d}^{#1}{} \!}%
}

\makeatother

...
```

The `\@ifmtarg` switch relies on neither `\empty` nor `\@empty`.

Comment: I would prefer to have code not bounded to a 3rd-party package.

Comment: @Igor: Note that `\@ifmtarg` is quite a short macro. So you could easily define it yourself if you don't like to load external packages.