# Commands with Capital letters in their name

Tags: macros, math-operators, package-writing, documentclass-writing, syntax

A topic that appear over and over is to explain the difference about commands such as `\operatorname` vs. `\DeclareMathOperator`. So far I've seen discussions about using one or the other, but no one explains if there is a substantial difference between them.

My question, however, goes a bit further. I *believe* that commands with capital letters in their names are a sort of *special* commands, say a lower level language of the programming (Am I right?).

Thus,

**Questions**

- What is (are) the difference(s) between `\operatorname` and `\DeclareMathOperator`?
- Is it customary to reserve "capitalised" commands to writing of classes?
- In the same spirit, What is the difference between `\usepackage` and `\RequirePackage`

I'll stop asking to avoid a lengthy post. Cheers.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48195/macro-naming-best-practice/48207#48207

Comment: Also have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55630/why-does-the-latex-kernel-define-usepackage-and-requirepackage

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer referenced in the comments answers the general question (and "yes" to the midle item).

For the other two items:

`\operatorname` is a document-level command that typesets a name at that point `\operatorname{foo}` typesets `foo` with the spacing and font of an operator. `\DeclareMathOperator` is a package level command that defines a command that prodiuces an operator name.

`\usepackage` and `\RequirePackage` are identical apart from their name the definition of the former is `\let\usepackage\RequirePackage`

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that this (`\DeclareMathOperator`) is a case where the distinction between package and document level commands is blurred. I certainly use `\DeclareMathOperator` in documents.

Comment: @IanThompson sure but probably in the preamble (which is essentially a local unnamed package) you wouldn't I assume use it like `\operatorname` in the middle of a formula?

Comment: I do use it in the preamble, which I never really thought of as a package. It seems the distinction between a package and a document is also blurred!

Comment: @IanThompson In my mental model the _document_ begins at `\begin{document}` (there is a hint in the syntax:-) (the `\usepackage/\RequirePackage` distinction breaks that model, but life's complicated)