# \subfigure errors with ASME template

Tags: subfloats, sublime-text

I am having some troubles in using \subfigure in LaTeX template for ASME conference papers, [version 1.7](http://iel.ucdavis.edu/code/ASME/conf-1.7b.html). Here's my code:

#### Figure

```
% GRAPHICS
\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}   

 \begin{figure}[t]
    \begin{center}
    \subfigure[Main Effect Plot]{
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,keepaspectratio]{Figure/Main_Effects_Plot.pdf}
        \label{fig:main_eff_plot}}
    \subfigure[Interaction Plot]{
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,keepaspectratio]{Figure/Interaction_Plot.pdf}
        \label{fig:inter_plot}}
    \end{center}
    \caption{FACTORIAL PLOT}
    \end{figure}
```

#### Errors in LaTeX source

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfigure/subfigure.sty:113: LaTeX Error: No counter 'figure' defined. [\newcounter{subfigure}[figure]]
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfigure/subfigure.sty:126: LaTeX Error: No counter 'table' defined. [\newcounter{subtable}[table]]
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfigure/subfigure.sty:413: LaTeX Error: Command \subref already defined. [  \ref{sub@#1}}]
./asme2e.tex:360: Undefined control sequence. [\begin{quotation}]
./asme2e.tex:360: Undefined control sequence. [\begin{quotation}]
```

Any help?

Comment: Don't use `\RequirePackage`, just use `\usepackage` (see [Why does the LaTeX kernel define \usepackage *and* \RequirePackage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55630/why-does-the-latex-kernel-define-usepackage-and-requirepackage)). Also, all of these should be **before** `\begin{document}`, in what is called the preamble to the document. And, finally, only use `subcaption`, don't also use `subfigure` (see [subcaption vs. subfig: Best package for referencing a subfigure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure)).

Comment: Using just  `\usepackage{captino}`, `\usepackage{subcaption}` and `\usepackage{graphics} in the preamble give me these errors:

`./asme2e.tex:258: Undefined control sequence. [\subfigure]`
`./asme2e.tex:261: Undefined control sequence. [\subfigure]`

Comment: That's because `subfigure` is defined as an environment in the `subcaption` package---*i.e.*, you use `\begin{subfigure}` and `\end{subfigure}` instead of `\subfigure{}`. You can take a look at the [`subcaption` documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/caption/subcaption.pdf) or just see [@Gonzalo's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164737/32888).

Comment: @Adam Done but the outcome doesn't change :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`subfigure` is an obsolete package which shouldn't be used anymore; you can use [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) instead.

An example with `subcaption`:

```
\documentclass{asme2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,keepaspectratio]{Figure/Main_Effects_Plot.pdf}
\caption{Main Effect Plot}
\label{fig:main_eff_plot}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,keepaspectratio]{Figure/Interaction_Plot.pdf}
\caption{Interaction Plot}
\label{fig:inter_plot}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{FACTORIAL PLOT}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An example with `subfig`:

```
\documentclass{asme2e}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\subfloat[Main Effect Plot\label{fig:main_eff_plot}]{%
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,keepaspectratio]{Figure/Main_Effects_Plot.pdf}
}\hfill
\subfloat[Interaction Plot\label{fig:inter_plot}]{%
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,keepaspectratio]{Figure/Interaction_Plot.pdf}
}%
\caption{FACTORIAL PLOT}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Notice that loading `caption`or `subcaption` with your class will issue a warning:

> Unsupported document class (or package) detected, usage of the caption
>   package is not recommended.See the caption package documentation for
>   explanation

which indicates that using the `caption` package *might* not be convenient. In this case, if you want to be sure that caption won't produce any interference with the way `asme2e` handles captions, you can use `subfig` with the `caption=false` option as in my last example.

Comment: Your first example give many erros: 
`./asme2e.tex:270: LaTeX Error: Environment subfigure undefined. [\begin{subfigure}]`
`./asme2e.tex:270: Missing number, treated as zero. [\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}]`
`./asme2e.tex:270: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). [\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}]`
`./asme2e.tex:274: LaTeX Error: \begin{figure} on input line 268 ended by \end{subfigure}. [\end{subfigure}]`
`./asme2e.tex:275: LaTeX Error: Environment subfigure undefined. [\begin{subfigure}]`

Comment: @gmeroni Update you LaTeX system.

Comment: and:`./asme2e.tex:275: Missing number, treated as zero. [\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}]`
`./asme2e.tex:275: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). [\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}]`
`./asme2e.tex:279: LaTeX Error: \begin{figure} on input line 268 ended by \end{subfigure}. [\end{subfigure}]`

Comment: @gmeroni In any case, as I mentioned in my last edit, with classes not supported by the `caption` package, you can always use `subfig`, as in the second code.

Comment: I just updated my LaTeX system but even with ´subfig´ i stil have [these](http://cl.ly/image/1m2K362J400E/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-10%20at%2020.55.32.png) errors. The ´subcaption´ give me [these](http://cl.ly/image/0B0x1D1E1d38/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-10%20at%2020.57.20.png)

Comment: @gmeroni if you're using `subfig`, you should *not* be using the `subfigure` environment. Take a look at Gonzalo's example in his answer.

Comment: @Adam I've pasted the exacly code written by Gonzalo :) I've found in a .cls document [these](http://cl.ly/text/2s2R0p07432i/Tables%20and%20Figures%20setcountert.txt) lines...

Comment: @gmeroni Please update your question with a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). I think that will make it easiest for us to help you.

Comment: @Adam Can't because all settings and parameters are in .cls file...I just grab the ASME template from [here](http://iel.ucdavis.edu/code/ASME/conf-1.7b.html) and pasted the Gonzalo's code. In the .cls i just added those two packages...

Comment: Made it! Those packages need to be added to the .tex instead to the .cls

Comment: For future reference, you *can* construct a MWE in this case. All you need to do is make a minimal `.tex` file that exhibits your problem and then link us to the `.cls` file. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: There's a newer latex template for ASME conferences in CTAN, which includes a working example of subfigures:  [https://ctan.org/pkg/asmeconf](https://ctan.org/pkg/asmeconf)

Comment: In first example you are saying that is an exsample of `subcaption` but you are using `subfigure`. What is wrong?