# Define a command for italic, bold and centered title inside a quote

Tags: macros, environments, quoting

Inside my quote, I have a bold, italic and centered header. How can I define a command so that I can typeset this text all in one go? I tried:

`\newcommand{\QuoteTitle}[1]{\centerline{\textit{\textbf{#1}}}}`

but it just jammed the whole thing on one line!

Here is what I need it to look like, given this input:

```
\begin{quote}
``\QuoteTitle{Quot paria coniculorum in uno anno ex uno pario germinentur.}

Qvidam posuit unum par cuniculorum in quodam loco, qui erat undique
pariete circundatus, ut sciret, quot ex eo paria germinarentur in uno
....''
\end{quote}
```

*should* produce the following output:

[image]

Comment: `\begin{center}``\textit{\textbf{#1}}\end{center}`?

Comment: @drozzy `\centerline` is a TeX command and it does what it states. It centers the text on one line. Go with Marc's suggestion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it might be easier to instead redefine the `quote` environment to take an optional argument, so that it could be used as

```
\begin{quote}
...
\end{quote}
```

or

```
\begin{quote}[Title goes here]
...
\end{quote}
```

So, in the code below, that's exactly what I've done, using

```
\let\oldquote\quote
\let\oldendquote\endquote
```

and then, borrowing the 'empty' test from [What is the difference between \empty and \@empty?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28787/what-is-the-difference-between-empty-and-empty) to redefine the `quote` environment as

```
\renewenvironment{quote}[1][]{\oldquote%
        \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
        ``
        \else
            \begin{center}%
            ``{\bfseries\itshape #1}%
            \end{center}\nobreak
        \fi}{''\oldendquote}
```

[image: screenshot]

Here's the complete MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldquote\quote
\let\oldendquote\endquote

\renewenvironment{quote}[1][]{\oldquote%
        \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
        ``
        \else
            \begin{center}%
            ``{\bfseries\itshape #1}%
            \end{center}\nobreak
        \fi}{''\oldendquote}

\begin{document}

\begin{quote}
  Qvidam posuit unum par cuniculorum in quodam loco, qui erat undique
  pariete circundatus, ut sciret, quot ex eo paria germinarentur in un
  Qvidam posuit unum par cuniculorum in quodam loco, qui erat undique
  pariete circundatus, ut sciret, quot ex eo paria germinarentur in un
\end{quote}

\begin{quote}[Here's one with a title]
  Qvidam posuit unum par cuniculorum in quodam loco, qui erat undique
  pariete circundatus, ut sciret, quot ex eo paria germinarentur in un
  Qvidam posuit unum par cuniculorum in quodam loco, qui erat undique
  pariete circundatus, ut sciret, quot ex eo paria germinarentur in un
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Great suggestion. Do you think it would make sense to create a new environment, instead of redefining the old one? I mean I only need this twice in a book... Something like `\begin{TitleQuote}[Title]...`?

Comment: Hm... this wouldn't work if I use something like csquotes package, would it? Well, that's a different question that I will ask! Cheers.

Comment: @drozzy it's up to you if you want to create a new environment :) if so, you don't need to mess around with the `\let` business, and just use `\newenvironment{titlequote}[1][]{....` etc. glad it helped!