# Can't use caption in new environment

Tags: captions, environments

I am trying to make some consistent tables and looked into the `nenenvironment`command. However, I am having trouble having a caption and using the defined environment at the same time.

newenvironment definition:

```
\newenvironment{mytable}[1]
{
    \begin{table}[ht]
        #definitions go here
            \begin{tabular}{#1}
}
{
            \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
}
```

If I have this, I get no error, and everything works ok:

```
\begin{mytable}{ccc}
cell & cell & cell \\
\end{mytable}
```

However, if I just add the `\caption` command like this:

```
\begin{mytable}{ccc}
cell & cell & cell \\
\caption{caption}
\end{mytable}
```

I get this error:

```
Missing \endgroup inserted. [\caption{caption}]
```

Comment: You're including the caption in the `tabular` environment, which is not allowed.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Any possible workaround?

Comment: I don't think you gain anything with such an environment. You just spare `\begin{tabular}` and `\end{tabular}`, losing in flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way that you define your environment, borrowing some code from [What is the difference between \empty and \@empty?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28787/what-is-the-difference-between-empty-and-empty)

```
\newenvironment{mytable}[2][]{%
    \begin{table}[ht]
        %definitions go here
        \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
        \else
        \caption{#1}
        \fi
        \centering
            \begin{tabular}{#2}
}
{%
            \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
}
```

It takes one *mandatory* argument (the alignment, such as `ccc`), and one *optional* argument, which is the `caption`. It can be used as

```
\begin{mytable}[caption]{ccc}
```

or

```
\begin{mytable}{ccc}
```

I'm not convinced this is a good idea though- you can probably just about use `label` still, but it seems unnatural. One of the other things that won't be easy to solve is that the `caption` command takes an optional argument that writes to the `lof`. You could probably solve this using the [`xparse`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/xparse) package, but all of this for something that was supposed to save time :)

```
\documentclass{article}


\newenvironment{mytable}[2][]{%
    \begin{table}[ht]
        %definitions go here
        \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
        \else
        \caption{#1}
        \fi
        \centering
            \begin{tabular}{#2}
}
{%
            \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytable}[caption]{ccc}
    1   &   2   &   3   \\
\end{mytable}
\end{document}
```