# Defining a newenvironment with optional caption

Tags: tables, captions, environments

I am trying to define a new table environment with optional caption. However, if I don't pass it the caption, I am still getting the "Table 1.1:" below the table. What am I missing here? Thanks. Examples below.

If I call it like this, it works as supposed.

```
\begin{mytable}[This is the caption]
% table content goes here
\end{mytable}
```

But if I call it like this, I get the "Table 1.1:" but nothing after. In the case with no caption provided, I obviously would like for the "Table 1.1:" not to appear.

```
\begin{mytable}
% table content goes here
\end{mytable}
```

newenvironment definition:

```
\def\mycaption{\relax}
\newenvironment{mytable}[1][]
{
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \gdef\mycaption{\relax}
    \else
    \gdef\mycaption{#1}
    \fi
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
            \begin{tabular}{lccc}
                & \textbf{\vocalsn} & \textbf{\nonvocalsn} & \textit{Totals} \\
                \hline
}
{
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \caption{\mycaption}
        \fi
    \end{table}
}
```

Comment: didn't I already answer this in [Can't use caption in new environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102851) ? :)

Comment: It's very similar yes, but it has the difference that I would like a environment with only 1 optional argument whereas your answer in that other question if for 1 mandatory and 1 optional argument. Basically, my code is adapted from yours to achieve that desired result. But for some reason, I am not getting it. If you would care to take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you always execute `\caption` so you will always get a caption even if the text of the caption is empty. Put the call to `\caption` into the redefinition of `\mycaption`, e.g.,

```
...
  \gdef\mycaption{}%
\else
  \gdef\mycaption{\caption{#1}}%
\fi
...
\mycaption
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit simpler with `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytable}{ o }
 {\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lccc}
    & \textbf{\vocalsn} & \textbf{\nonvocalsn} & \textit{Totals} \\
  \hline}
 {\hline
  \end{tabular}
  \IfValueT{#1}{\caption{#1}}
  \end{table}}
```

With `xparse` you can use the arguments also in the "end part"; the condition `\IfValue...` is true only if the optional argument is specified, so with

```
\IfValueT{#1}{\caption{#1}}
```

you insert the caption only if the optional argument is actually expressed.