# \insertshortpart is never empty?

Tags: beamer, themes

I would like to use `\insertshortpart` (with some surrounding characters) in a Beamer theme, but only if a short part is actually available. However, if I try to check for emptiness with `\ifx...\empty` it turns out that this expression is never true.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\ifx\insertpart\empty
empty part
\else
non-empty part
\fi

\ifx\insertshortpart\empty
empty short part
\else
non-empty short part
\fi
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This results in "empty part" and "non-empty short part".

How can I check if the short part is actually empty?

I had a similar problem with `\insertshortdate`, `\insertshorttitle` and `\insertshortsubtitle` which I could solve by using `\beamer@shortdate`, `\beamer@shorttitle` and `\beamer@shortsubtitle` instead, respectively.
For `\insertshortpart`, however, I couldn't find a replacement.

BTW, what's the difference between `\empty` and `\@empty`? In my style file both seem to work ...

Comment: For the difference between `\empty` and `\@empty`, see [What is the difference between \empty and \@empty?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28787/what-is-the-difference-between-empty-and-empty).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short part name is stored in `\beamer@partnameshort`, which however is undefined before a `\part` command is issued.

Here's a test for it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ifemptyshortpart}{%
  \@ifundefined{beamer@partnameshort}
    {\@firstoftwo}
    {\ifx\beamer@partnameshort\@empty
       \expandafter\@firstoftwo
     \else
       \expandafter\@secondoftwo
     \fi}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\ifemptyshortpart{\typeout{EMPTY}}{\typeout{NON EMPTY}}

\part[Short]{Long}
\ifemptyshortpart{\typeout{EMPTY}}{\typeout{NON EMPTY}}

\part[]{Long}
\ifemptyshortpart{\typeout{EMPTY}}{\typeout{NON EMPTY}}

\part{Long}
\ifemptyshortpart{\typeout{EMPTY}}{\typeout{NON EMPTY}}

\end{document}
```

The output on the terminal is

```
EMPTY
NON EMPTY
EMPTY
NON EMPTY
```

Note that you get empty only if no `\part` command has been issued or `\part` is issued with an explicit empty optional argument. Otherwise `beamer` stores in `\beamer@partnameshort` the long version.

The `\ifemptyshortpart` command should be followed by the "true" and "false" branches:

```
\ifemptyshortpart{short part is empty}{short part is non empty}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you add

```
\show\insertshortpart
```

you will see its definition is

```
> \insertshortpart=macro:
->\@protected@testopt \insertshortpart \\insertshortpart {}.
```

which is not the same definition as `\@empty` even if it produces no text.

You can grab this definition at the start and use it in the test:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\origiginsertshortpart\insertshortpart
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
%\show\insertpart
\ifx\insertpart\empty
empty part
\else
non-empty part
\fi

%\show\insertshortpart
\ifx\insertshortpart\origiginsertshortpart
empty short part
\else
non-empty short part
\fi
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should probably accept @egreg's answer but I'll let this one stand as it shows why your original `\ifx` test failed.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Your suggestion works in my minimal example. However, when I actually define a part, it ceases to work. It seems that it always shows "empty short part".

Comment: Yes that's right, I had (have) no idea what the command does so basically I was just explaining why the code in the question doesn't work. However I suspect that when you do use it the top level definition as seen by `\ifx` doesn't actually change. As I noted in the first comment above, I only left this answer rather than deleting it as it has the explanation of why your original code didn't work. Just do what @egreg says (he's sometimes right about TeX:-)